# django forms error not shown

Tags: django, forms

I'm trying to create a form. Here is my form class:

```
class RegisterForm(forms.Form):
login=forms.CharField(min_length=5,max_length=15)
password=forms.CharField(min_length=5,max_length=15,widget=forms.PasswordInput)
passwordConfirmation=forms.CharField(min_length=5,max_length=15,label="Re enter password",widget=forms.PasswordInput)
email=forms.EmailField(min_length=5,max_length=20)
question=forms.CharField(min_length=8,max_length=20,label="Security question")
answer=forms.CharField(min_length=5,max_length=20,widget=forms.PasswordInput)
answerConfirmation=forms.CharField(min_length=5,max_length=20,label="Re enter answer",widget=forms.PasswordInput)'
```

And now i have tamplate as follow:

```
{% if form.login.errors %}
{{ form.login.errors }}
{% endif %}
{{ form.login }}<label for="login">Enter desired login</label><br />
```

And so on i just only change form.name etc. to one from the forms class.
And when i filled form incorrect i don't get any error or nothing just blank form. Where I made a mistake? Thx for help
Edit:
Sorry i forget to show my function here is it

```
def register(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form=RegisterForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/register')
    else:
        form = RegisterForm(auto_id=False)
        return render_to_response('misc/register.html',locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request))
else:
    form=RegisterForm(auto_id=False)
    return render_to_response('misc/register.html',locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Did you call is_valid on form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've redeclared the form in the first else clause,  so you've overwritten the errors.  Drop that else clause completely,  bring the very last line back one indent,  so it catches the case when the firm is not valid.

Answer (score 2):

```
form = RegisterForm(auto_id=False)
```

On this line you are creating new blank form and all validation errors are lost. Comment it out.

Comment: Ok thx Daniel,Vladimir for help now it's working perfectly. Thank both of you very much.